# CustomGridView not working, not showing anything

Tags: android, gridview

im on coding 1 mini app with vooley-mySql and now, i converting it to SQLite, but my gridview not showing anything, i dont know why, data loading good but not show.
im trying to use ArrayAdapter and work, but my app need customAdapter with image. pls helpme

CustomGridView_Home.java: http://www.paste.org/88161

Fragment_home.java:http://www.paste.org/88162

SQLheper:http://www.paste.org/88163

Comment: please add your code in the question, i doubt anyone will look at it!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapter file:

```
public class CustomProductsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

TextView textView;
ImageView imageView;
String[] title = new String[]{};
String[] image = new String[]{};
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

public CustomProductsAdapter(Context context, String[] title, String[] image) {

    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, null);
    textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    return view;
}}
```

IN Activity initialize the gridview and set the Adapter Where title and images you need to send as List,Map,Array

```
GridView products= (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.products_grid);
                  products.setAdapter(new CustomProductsAdapter(getContext(),title,image);
                  setDynamicHeight(products);
```

dynamic height method is here:

```
public void setDynamicHeight(GridView gridView) {
    ListAdapter gridViewAdapter = gridView.getAdapter();
    if (gridViewAdapter == null) {
    return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    int items = gridViewAdapter.getCount();
    int rows = 0;

    View listItem = gridViewAdapter.getView(0, null, gridView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight = listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

    float x = 1;
    if( items > 4 ){
    x = items / 4;
    if (x >= 2){
    x = x-1;
    }
    rows = (int) (x + 1);
    totalHeight *= rows;
    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight;
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

Gridview in activity xml:

```
<GridView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/products_grid"
                  android:numColumns="4"
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                  android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_8"
                  android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_14"
                  android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_24"
                  />
```

Grid in Adapter file for injection

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/bus" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12"
    android:textColor="@color/mildblack"
    android:text="Image Name" />
```

Comment: Sorry for multiple edit. stackoverflow editor prompt me error so the delay,Hope you find the solution